# replace autocompletion popup in Sublime Text on keybinding

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to write a plugin that gives autocompletion of database tables in autocompletion popup (additional popup that is fired from some key binding).

I've cached database table names in xml file.

I can add these table names to autocompetion list by overriding sublime_plugin.EventListener on_query_completions method. But I want to have ability to use both autocompletion popups independently?

Is there possibility to do this?

**UPD:** Example of what I want to achieve:

When I type something - autocomplete works as usual. But when I press alt+f6 in autocomplete dropdown should be only table names that I've cached.

Comment: All `EventListener` will invoked and all available auto complete list should be merged together. So what's your question? Could you please give an example to demonstrate what your need?

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't know how to achieve this.